# Ошибка компиляции в C++: перегруженные функции имеют похожие преобразования

Tags: c++, ооп

Я хотел сделать перегрузку оператор ==, что бы сравнить 2 объекта класса. Но у меня выдаёт ошибку.

**Код**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    void PrintInfo()
    {
        printf("Точка имеет координаты [%d;%d]\n", x, y);
    }

    bool operator == (const Point& object)
    {
        return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    
    Point a(5, 1);
    Point b(9, 4);

    bool result = a == b;

    cout << result << endl;
}
```

**Сама ошибка**:

[image: Ошибка компиляции]

Надеюсь на помощь и объяснение, почему данная ошибка возникает:) Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: В приведенном коде заявленная ошибка не возникает. https://godbolt.org/z/1xq3199xh Также ошибки следует приводить в виде текста.

Comment: @user7860670 если бы не возникало ошибки, я бы не задавал вопрос. Человек, написавший ниже, решил мою проблему.

Comment: Если ошибка возникает, то в вопросе необходимо приводить [mcve], иначе вопрос является оффтопиком. Ошибка считается реально возникающей не когда вы об этом заявляете, а когда ее могут воспроизвести читающие вопрос. А еще лучше - сразу приводите ссылку на онлайн компилятор.

Comment: @user7860670 Проблем-то :) Вот, держите, ссылка на онлайн-компилятор: https://godbolt.org/z/MjnfGrKns

Comment: @Harry ¿Вы и ОП - одно лицо?

Comment: @user7860670 ОП — это что за аббревиатура?...

Comment: @Harry Original Poster, то бишь тот, кто создал топик

Comment: @user7860670 А где в правилах, что комментировать может только OP? Ну что вы демагогией занимаетесь...

Comment: @Harry *"А где в правилах, что комментировать может только OP? Ну что вы демагогией занимаетесь"* - ¿к чему вы это вообще пишите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да исправить-то его несложно, надо просто не лениться и не скупиться на `const` везде, где можно :)

```
bool operator == (const Point& object) const
```

и далее по тексту...

А вот откуда [C2666](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2666?view=msvc-170) — лично мне пока не очень понятно, вроде ничему из описанного по ссылке ситуация не соответствует. И что значит

> может быть  "bool Point::operator ==(const Point &)" [синтезированное выражение "y == x"].

Был бы признателен пояснениям гуру в стандартах.

P.S. Для неверующих в ошибку...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, если поставить ключик стандарта c++17 или с++14, то ошибки нет. Но при c++20 здесь есть ошибка. Вот потому и прошу гуру пояснить, что там такого, в С++20, добавилось.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. После того, как в конце функции я дописал const, всё заработало без ошибок. Я хотел бы спросить, а что означает const в конце функции?

Comment: *"откуда C2666 — лично мне пока не очень понятно"* - это не удивительно, ведь ее нет

Comment: @user7860670 См. обновленный ответ

Comment: ¿Что ж вы докатились до картинки с текстом? А в С++20 (который в вопросе не упоминается) добавили https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: @user7860670 Побоялся, что иначе не поверите. Ведь тому, что я *написал*, вы не поверили. Вот и пришлось давать картинку, в которой еще и первой давать исходник. А то опять бы не поверили...